# plt.savefig behaviour in eps mode for nan type using imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, nan, imshow, savefig

I am trying to save an image using `plt.imshow` and `plt.savefig` by inputting a certain 2D array that happens to contain NaNs. When I call `plt.show()` the NaNs map to white but when saved to an eps file they become black.

Here is my MWE, I have set some of the values of `data` to NaN and they appear black in my .eps file upon saving, depsite showing up initially as white in `plt.show()` or when saving to a png file.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
#MWE
data = np.ones([10,10]) #dummy values
data[:,5] = np.nan #set some to NaN for example

image = plt.imshow(data)
cbar = plt.colorbar(image)

plt.show()
plt.savefig("my_image.eps",format="eps")
```

[image]

[image]

Am I missing something or is this just a bug ? If not is there a way around this ?

Comment: `cmap = mpl.colormaps.get_cmap('viridis')` , `cmap.set_bad(color='white')` and `image = plt.imshow(data, cmap=cmap)`, as the default is `'k'`

Comment: Additionally, `.savefig` comes before `plt.show`